# CLT for dependant random variables

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, limit-theorems

I define a distribution of probability $L$ on $C:=C_0([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ the set of continuous functions $f$ on $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$. I suppose that $L$ is centered and has a covariance function. To fix the ideas, one can think at the distribution given by the brownian bridge.
Then, for any fixed $\epsilon>0$, I define a process $(\Gamma_n)_{n\geq 0}$ taking values in $C$ as follows :

1. $\Gamma_0$ can be any random initial condition.
2. for every $n\geq 1$, I resample $\Gamma_{n-1}$ on an interval $[y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon]$ chosen uniformly in $[0,1]$. This means that I "erase" the previous value of $\Gamma_{n-1}$ on this interval, and I "fill the hole" by adding a new **rescaled** and **independent** version of $L$ on the interval. I attached a picture for more clarity

[image: (picture)].

My question is now : do we have theorems to ensure that, as $n\mapsto \infty$, the variables $\Gamma_n-\Gamma_0$ converge in law to a gaussian distribution on $C$ ? Or similarly does it exists a version of the Central Limit Theorem for the integrals $\int_0^1 (\Gamma_n-\Gamma_0)(x) f(x) dx$ for any fixed smooth $f$ ?
It seems to me that it should be true, but the problem is that the increments $\Gamma_n - \Gamma_{n-1}$ are of the form $g_n - h_n$ where $g_n$ is the part I "add" and $h_n$ is the part I "erase", and the $h_n$ are not independent, such that I cannot simply apply the classical TCL.

Thanks a lot for reading this post.

PS : the martingale CLT (see for example the book of Ethier & Kurtz) does not apply here, since the term $-h_n$ is measurable with respect to the filtration $\mathcal{F}_{n-1} := \sigma(\Gamma_m ~:~m\leq n-1)$ and non-zero, such that it's not a martingale.

Comment: I saved it to take a look at this again, but perhaps it will help to look a similar construction here: http://sites.math.washington.edu/~rohde/papers/conformal%20welding%20of%20dendrites.pdf

Comment: There they construct an "excursion-exploration" process too and they need to use Galton-Watson tree technology to make sense of the limiting object.

Comment: Thanks already for the reference, I'll take a look !